How can I extend a type with additional property?
I want to extend a type. How can I do it?
declare type IntervalType =
  | "day"
  | "week"
  | "month",
  ...

type currentIntervalTypes = IntervalType[] & "year";
const intervalTypes: extendedIntervalTypes = [
  "day",
  "month",
  "year",
];

typescript error: Type "year" is not assignable to type

Are currentIntervalTypes and extendedIntervalTypes meant to be the same type in this example?

You aren't trying to combine types, you're trying to add another option to a union, so you will need to use |
declare type IntervalType =
  | "day"
  | "week"
  | "month"

type extendedIntervalTypes = Array<IntervalType | "year">;
const intervalTypes: extendedIntervalTypes = [
  "day",
  "month",
  "year",
];

